# Can't login to authorize upgrade to Umbraco 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, migrating

I'm trying to migrate my Umbraco 7.13 to Umbraco 8.1. I'm using [this guide](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/upgrading/migrating-to-v8). I've succesfully completed step 1 so my site is now using version 7.14. I've set my connectionstring and i changed the version in my web.config to 7.14.0 but when i lauch it it will go to a login screen where I can't login to authorize the upgrade (url is http://localhost:59950/umbraco/AuthorizeUpgrade?redir=%2finstall%2f%3fredir%3dtrue%26url%3dhttp%253a%252f%252flocalhost%253a59950%252fumbraco#/login/false?returnPath=%252Fcontent). I can't login with the account created in the setup, which is logicall cause I'm using a different database now, and I can't login using the accounts made in 7.13.

I've stumbled across [this issue](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/5953) and tried the suggested solve but that didn't work for me. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it is the actual problem mentioned in that github issue.

Could you please verify that in your web.config of your new site, you have the same settings/attributes in `UsersMembershipProvider` as you do on your v7 site.

Also make sure that if you have entered a custom machinekey in your web.config - this needs to be the same in the new v8 site in order to hash passwords the same way (and validate your login).

Comment: It was cause of the machinekey! thank you very much.